# Automatically build project before Add-Migration or Update-Database commands

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two different projects that use Entity Framework, to generate my migrations I use the commands `Add-Migration name` and `Update-Database`.

Now, for some reason, the first project always makes sure that my project is built with the latest code by issuing a build after every one of these commands that I do inside `Pacakge Manager Console`.

This is what I see as the correct way.

But my second project, despite being very similar, it never do that build automatically as the first one does.

So If I need to generate a new migration, I first run a build, then run `Add-Migration name`, then build again, then run `Update-Database`.

Is there a option somewhere that I'm not aware that enables or disables that behavior?

Ps. my visual studio version is 2017 Enterprise

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First I would love to comment instead giving an answer but I can't yet.

In your startup file in the first project do you have something similar to this?

```
dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

Or

```
dbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

If the answer is yes that's maybe why in one of your projects when you start it the project update the database.

Comment: I looked at the project but couldn't find these lines, also, I think that is specific to EF Core right? I'm using EF 6 actually

Comment: Oh, my bad for not asking first which EF version you were using. Let me try some things and I'll be back with an answer.